# How to deal cards according to probabilities?

Tags: probability, sampling, conditional-probability

Moved here from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66639562) as it is a logical problem not really a coding one.

I am trying to come up with an algorithm to deal single cards to players given a probability distribution. This can be thought of as a dealer who is cheating and wants to give certain cards to certain players but doesn't want to be obvious. So I want to get as many cards as players (no players having the same card as others).

Example probabilities for a three card deck and three players:

|  | Ace | King | Queen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Player 1** | 0% | 66% | 33% |
| **Player 2** | 33% | 33% | 33% |
| **Player 3** | 66% | 0% | 33% |

Choosing player by player can lead to situations when the remaining player has 0% probability to get the remaining card. In the above example - what if **Player 1** gets a **Queen**, **Player 2** gets an **Ace**. Then **Player 3** cannot get any card as his **King** probability is 0%.

---

One way I tried is to deal the cards per player. Then check if there are duplicates and if there are I deal again till there are no duplicate cards. Averaging the samples to get a distribution
does **not** match the probability distribution that I want to sample from.

The reason for this (in the example above) is that the re-dealing would happen more often for **Player 1** getting **Queen** because the chance of a duplicate in that case is 66% unlike when **Player 1** gets a **King** (33%). This skews the resulting distribution.

---

Another way that I tried is to deal **Player 1**'s card. Then remove that from the possible **Player 2** cards and deal a card out of that for **Player 2**. The card for player 3 is the remaining card. This I saw is clearly stupid because **Player 3** can get a **King**s by this logic which should happen with 0% probability.

What would the steps be to make sure we sample following a given distribution **and** that we don't have duplicates?

Comment: I noticed that using rejection draw (sample per player independently and reject all if duplicate) can give the right distribution of results. But for it to work we have to bias the probabilities that we sample from. To get approximately the example distribution we can sample from: `[[0.0, 0.563, 0.437], [0.46666, 0.3, 0.23333], [0.666666, 0.0, 0.333333]]` Not sure how to work out how much we need to bias it by yet though.

Comment: Rejection sampling from `[[0, 0.5, 0.5], [0.333, 0.333, 0.333], [0.5, 0, 0.5]]` Gives exactly the same distribution as the example in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to sample Player 2's card first. With equal probability of 33%, he gets an A, K or Q.

- If Player 2 got an A, Player 1 gets a K and Player 3 a Q.
- If Player 2 got a K, Player 1 gets a Q and Player 3 an A.
- If Player 2 got a Q, Player 1 gets a K and Player 3 an A.

Overall, Player 1 has a 66% chance of getting a K (33% each of Player 2 getting an A or a Q) and a 33% chance of getting a Q (33% chance of Player 2 getting a K). And Player 3 similarly has a 66% chance of getting an A and a 33% chance of getting a Q. Just as required.

And you need precisely three cards: an A, a K and a Q.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not really asking for a specific solution to the example I gave but for a generic solution. Which I will use with 6 players and 52 cards.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Can you give some details about the prespecified distribution? Can we assume it is a valid one? Does it fulfill any constraints at all, apart from all rows and columns summing to 100%?

Comment: The columns do sum to one and yes we can assume it is valid. The pre-specified distribution begins with all of the cards being equally likely and then it is updated according to some information we gain. Keep in mind that the [update might not even be computationally feasible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66592945). In which case this is purely a hypothetical question.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand you correctly, you are trying to sample a single random permutation from the full permutation group $S_n$ (you are dealing $n$ cards to $n$ players), with weights. In your example, all permutations that start with $\pi_1=1$, i.e., that assign the Ace to Player 1, have zero probability. I don't know of a general algorithm, and a little searching on the internet didn't bring up anything useful. ...

Comment: ... Interestingly (and discouragingly for you, I'm afraid), even a simple rejection sampling scheme (draw cards one player after the other by the player's probability, reject the entire draw if we run into a zero probability) yields systematically biased results by my simulation. I thought that might be because I always want through the players in order, so I randomized the player order, and still get a bad bias. ...

Comment: ... I'm sorry, but I personally am at the end of my tether. Perhaps some deeper searching for "weighted sampling of random permutations" or similar may be helpful, or you may be able to go back to your original problem and cast it in a different way. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks anyway :)